# How cold is a dish that is served cold?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

There are several dishes that are best ***served cold***.

But, does this usually mean the "normal room temperature", or cold as in "frozen", or as when the food just comes out from a freezer or a fridge?

The latter is my default understanding.

So, [one of our answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24064/3281) saying *"Ketchup is usually served cold."* made me curious because it sounds more like "room temperature".

***How cold is a dish that is served cold?***

Comment: I think in this context "cold" means simply "not heated". "Cold roast beef" is not refrigerated beef, but  beef that has cooled after cooking. Ketchup may be refrigerated or may be room temperature, but it is not ordinarily heated before putting it on hot dogs.

Comment: If frozen it is below 32F/0C

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As with so many things, it depends.

When used in contrast to a *hot* alternative, *cold* simply means at or somewhat below room temperature. For example, the meat in a *hot pastrami sandwich* is heated on a skillet as part of its preparation and served hot, whereas a *cold pastrami sandwich* it is not.

Food is also *cold* if it is usually served heated, but has cooled off below the temperature where it is normally consumed. Thus, your lukewarm chicken noodle soup may still be warmer than the air, but you may still send it back to the kitchen as "cold."

If the temperature of a food were deliberately lowered as part of its preparation, with ice or refrigeration, it would be *chilled*. For example, you might have *chilled wine* served with your dinner and *chilled fruit* for dessert.

Sometimes, *hot* and *cold* distinguish between levels of preparation. A cold lunch would be one brought from home (aka *sack lunch*), or a box lunch of a sandwich or fruit, as opposed to a hot lunch which would be a heated, prepared meal. Schools may offer a choice of [hot lunch or cold lunch](http://www.ramblingsofasuburbanmom.com/2013/09/a-poll-hot-lunch-or-cold-lunch/), for example.

Ketchup is a condiment, and so would almost always be *cold*, but would probably not be *chilled*.

---

I should note that with *beverages* as opposed to food, *cold* does sometimes mean *chilled*, at least in American English. You'll advertisements for *cold drinks*, typically meaning chilled fruity or fizzy soft drinks. A *cold beer* is idiomatically one that has been chilled below cellar temperature (well below room temperature)— we would not order *chilled beer* in a bar without raising some eyebrows.

But there are certain drinks which are taken hot or chilled, and never at room temperature. Thus, *cold coffee* or *cold cider* is hot coffee or cider that has been allowed to cool off— not something you can typically order. To get the truly cold alternative, you order *iced coffee* or *chilled cider*.

---

Lastly, there is the expression *[Revenge is a dish best served cold](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/revenge-is-a-dish-best-served-cold.html)*, but *cold* here is a play on words, referring to *cold-bloodedness* (i.e. [heartlessness or mercilessness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold-blooded)).

Comment: This is an *excellent* and comprehensive answer. I wish I could +9000!

Comment: I was about 6 when I disappointingly realised that things that are better cold (ice cream, drinks etc.) tend towards getting warmer. And things that are better warm (soup, and most meat) tend towards getting colder. I mention this because you can have warm pop, and cold soup that are both the same temperature. These terms are all relative.

Comment: I always took the `Revenge Is A Dish Best Served Cold` phrase as waiting to getting revenge until the offending party does not expect it.

Comment: @Elias, and also because it gives you more time to plan your revenge and relish in it. But this doesn't answer the question as to whether revenge should be served at fridge temperature or room temperature. And which type of relish goes best with it?

Comment: Cruncher, it's called _entropy_ (which always increases). @Elias, I take the expression primarily to mean "don't take your revenge while you're still hot and angry and impetuous, and could do something foolish (and get caught). Wait until your temper has cooled and you can go about the [crime or other unpleasantness] coolly and carefully." Your target may well have forgotten about it by then, or they may have been worrying the whole time.