# What do we call 'ketchup', 'cheesy dip' , 'oregano' and things like that collectively, as they aren't side dishes?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

With most of the Indian dishes, [we are served with something ***other*** than side dishes](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-UsHalO__EUQ/UyU06wlOpbI/AAAAAAAAd3E/37HvKzK5JVg/s1600/rava-dosa-breakfast.jpg) i.e. salads.

Since most of the users here come from different countries, I come up with stuff that is internationally known.

So, for instance, if we have a pizza, what do we call oregano, ketchup, chilli flakes, [cheesy dip](http://media.onsugar.com/files/2011/03/13/4/192/1922195/091ef7ab6df6530b_Honey_Mustard.xlarge.JPG) ***collectively***? I don't agree that they are [the side dishes.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/side-dish) That's because side dishes are *actually dishes* (you can certainly order 'salads'). But here, you cannot separately order ketchup, cheese dip and the like.

Are they fillers? I'm not sure. If there's no *one* single word, a close one would do.

Comment: Actually, some places do charge extra for sauces and seasonings - Papa John's, for one. And I know I've been to some burger joint where they charged for extra ketchup. But those are the exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Please don't put ketchup on pizza.  Please.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, sounds like you've never had a cheeseburger pizza. Ketchup, ground beef, cheese, onions, tomato, pickles. It's quite tasty.

Comment: @thumbtackthief many advise me this! But Indian tongue, cannot taste anything without *condiments!* Now, I have the word! :P

Comment: @MaulikV I'm a New Yorker!  Pizza and ketchup don't mix!  (and side note, since you're learning:  We'd say "many advise me _of_ this," but that's still formal and awkward--probably just say, "Many people tell me this!")

Comment: Your link on the 'cheesy dip' is to a picture of 'Honey Mustard' which is a completely different condiment.

Comment: @Warlord099 Oh I see..I could not get proper picture of cheesy dip what we have here in all McDs in India.

Comment: Since when is cheesey dip not only a dish but a meal in and of itself? In unrelated news I'm a terrible human being.

Comment: Not mentioned anywhere else that I saw: these are not *fillers*. We would say *filling* to refer to something completely contained inside another food (eg jam in a doughnut). *Filler* would mean something mediocre used to "fill the gap" between two things that are much better (eg a so-so minor course in the middle of a multi-stage meal, or a substandard meal between two proper ones), or maybe something designed to be heavy so that you feel extremely full (a very unlikely usage). But none of these meanings of *filler* are commonly used in talk about food or appropriate for the items listed.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

"Condiments" is probably the closest word to describing all of them.  Being more specific, ketchup is a sauce, cheesy dip is a sauce or a dip and oregano and chilli flakes might be described as seasonings (or just as herbs and spices).

Comment: I've upvoted the answer, but I would never call ketchup a "sauce." (Ketchup is a *condiment*, teriyaki is a *sauce*. Regional variations may apply.)

Comment: @J.R. Ketchup meets any definition of "sauce", and would certainly be referred to as one in the UK. Indeed, it's often informally referred to here as just "tomato sauce". (On the other hand, I accept that, in the US, you wouldn't expect ketchup if you were offered a sauce, in the same way that you wouldn't expect a cucumber anywhere, if offered a fruit.)

Comment: In almost all Indian dishes you'll find condiments and surprisingly, they play 'equal' role in making the dish delicious. If any of condiments is not up to the mark, many will criticize the main dish as well lol...just to share this funny thing! :)

Comment: Source for sauce: [OED 'sauce' n.1.a](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/171316): "*Any preparation, usually liquid or soft, and often consisting of several ingredients, intended to be eaten as an appetizing accompaniment to some article of food. †Formerly occas. applied to a condiment of any kind.*"

Comment: @AE Thank you. If I need to use that definition, I'll be sure to acknowledge you as my sauce source source.

Comment: It's here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/tomato-ketchup-vs-tomato-sauce I asked that.

Comment: In Australia, 'ketchup/catsup' is seen as an American word for tomato sauce.  We put dead horse on everything.

Comment: Good Research for this question!

Comment: @AE & David - I understand it (_ketchup_) meets the dictionary definition of a sauce, but I don't hear _sauce_ used that way in conversation – at least, not when referring to ketchup, mustard, or mayonnaise. I've never heard anyone ask, "Who's bringing the sauce(s) to the picnic?" (it's _condiments_), or, "Please pass the mustard; I want some more sauce on my burger." And, at least in the U.S., _tomato sauce_ = _spaghetti sauce_, which is quite unlike ketchup.

Comment: @J.R. but in BrEng 'tomato sauce' can definitely be ketchup (it can also be pasta sauce). We also have 'brown sauce' (HP sauce) which is another condiment. Mustard, however, is not a sauce, neither is mayonnaise. Condiments collectively could be sauces, I'm pretty sure I've been told in Wetherspoons (a pub chain) that "the sauces are over there".

Comment: @AE Yes, and it's common in pubs and similar restaurants to be asked "Would you like any sauces?" and that question is taken to include ketchup, mustard, mayo and any number of other cold liquidy substances that would probably be called condiments in the US.

Comment: @AE & David - Interesting! That's one thing I like about ELL: learning about other ways words are used – which is why I put the "regional variations" disclaimer in my initial comment :^) When this question first popped up yesterday, I thought about how many AmEng sauces use the word "sauce" in their name: soy sauce, teriyaki sauce, hollandaise sauce, steak sauce (I think that's what we'd call HP). We don't usually call something a "sauce" unless it's called a sauce, if that makes any sense. In the U.S., that's probably a pretty good dividing line between _sauces_ and _condiments_.

Comment: e.g. [tomato sauce](http://i.imgur.com/sQU14Zt.jpg), [HP sauce](http://i.imgur.com/f8F8CEW.jpg), [brown sauce](http://www.thedrum.com/uploads/news/177758/40235011_0_640x640.jpg), ["free ketchup too (and other sauces)"](http://www.hotukdeals.com/deals/wetherspoons-and-lloyds-small-chips-197688), ["The sauce - Heinz ketchup generously applied"](http://fryupsgoodornot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/special-feature-breakfast-on-budget.html) (that last one has more good 'sauce' cites). Transatlantic food products are a minefield!

Comment: @AE That first link is really interesting: I've never seen ketchup *formally* referred to as "tomato sauce" before. I thought it was just something that happened in speech. (I see the bottle in question is from New Zeeland, suggesting another level of the scale. US: "It's not a sauce, damnit!", UK: "It's a sauce and people informally call it that, but the manufacturer calls it ketchup", NZ: "Even the manufacturer calls it sauce."

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I suspect in the UK you might find generic brand tomato sauce referred to as such. I'll take a look next time I go to a supermarket (and then probably forget to come back here and report).

Comment: Also 'hot sauce' ([eg1](http://www.latestfreestuff.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/free-heinz-hot-sauce-bottle.jpg), [eg2](http://highlandsranchfoodie.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Bottles.jpg)). @DavidRicherby, I hear 'tomato sauce' and 'sauces' as more plain-spoken than 'ketchup' and 'condiments'. 'Condiments' seems more gourmet, 'sauces' seems more down-to-earth - and possibly more working-class? 'Condiments' having an air of pretentiousness about it perhaps? Or of corporate-speak?

Comment: ["Yorkshire Relish: The Most Delicious Cheapest And Best Sauce In The World"](http://www.foodsofengland.co.uk/foodsofengland%20yorkshirerelishposter.jpg): historic, now [YR Sauce](http://www.foodsofengland.co.uk/yorkshirerelish.htm). [Shropshire Sauce](http://www.foodsofengland.co.uk/shropshiresauce.htm), [Worcestershire Sauce](http://www.foodsofengland.co.uk/worcesterorworcestershiresauce.htm) (also used in cocktails).["Henderson's Relish: The Spicy Yorkshire Sauce"](http://www.british-american-food.de/WebRoot/Store16/Shops/63414000/50EC/0C2F/31E0/7236/611D/C0A8/28BE/B4B6/hendersonrelish.jpg)

Comment: @AE - I suspect that's your British ear. In the U.S., _condiments_ usually conjures to mind basic toppings for basic foods: my initial thought would be something like [this](http://c.shld.net/rpx/i/s/i/spin/image/spin_prod_ec_765415601?hei=546&wid=546&op_sharpen=1). On the other hand, _sauces_ might be for people who are "too good for ketchup."

Comment: This is about usage. Ketchup is absolutely a sauce, but Americans use it as a condiment, or a dip. We use gravy and salad dressing as condiments too.

Comment: 1,600 Google results for the vexed question of "is gravy a condiment?". 1,601 now.

Comment: @J.R., AE I wouldn't say 'condiments' is pretentious, but I'd agree 'sauces' has a cheaper feel. I'd argue they're two sets with not insignificant overlap. Cheese sauce is in S and not in C, mint sauce is in S and C, and redcurrant jelly is in C and not in S.

Answer (score 14):

In US English:

- On pizza (before it's baked), you put toppings.
- On a sandwich, you put condiments.
- On a plate, you put sauce.
- In a bowl (for dipping) is a dip.
- Something shaken over is a seasoning.

There is no one word to refer to these collectively.  If you order Papa John's and they forget anything, one would ask "Where's all the stuff that comes with it?"

Comment: The "toppings" on a pizza are the things that the chef puts it on it before baking, which doesn't seem very relevant to the question.

Comment: "toppings" can be also used (in parts of the US) to refer to things on a sandwich, including condiments, for example vegetables. For example, a sandwich restaurant might ask what "toppings" you want to add to the basic sandwich and you might say "lettuce, tomato, mustard"

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned having pizza: "So, for instance, if we have pizza, what do we call..."

Comment: You could put 'toppings' on a sandwich, but only in certain circumstances such as Subway or a "toppings bar".

Comment: @boatseller Yes, the question mentions pizza. But it's about things that you put on the pizza yourself, at the table, not about things that the chef put on the pizza before baking it. Your answer is unclear: it seems to start by saying that anything put on a pizza is a topping but then at the end, you say that there's no collective word for all of the things you might put on a pizza. Please clarify this.

Comment: +1 for "there is no one word to refer to these collectively." In the U.S., I think _condiments_ comes closest and could do in a pinch, but if you're hosting an event, and ask Tony to "bring condiments," don't be surprised if he doesn't bring oregano, and assumes someone else is taking care of the _seasonings_ and the _dips_. There are also _dressings_, which are usually put on salads (though dressings can be used as condiments on sandwiches, too, and a ranch dressing may be used as a dip, or as a base for a dip).

Answer (score 5):

You add tomato sauce on a pizza before you bake it, then when it's almost cooked you can add the chopped mozzarella cheese and pop it back in the oven in order for the cheese to melt. I tend to add the fresh basil leaves when the pizza has finished baking :)

1. The tomato base of a pizza is the *[sauce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sauce)*.
2. The cheese on the pizza is the [topping](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/topping).
3. The basil and oregano are fresh/dried [herbs](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/herb?q=herbs).
4. The salt and pepper are the [seasoning](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seasoning).
5. Mayonnaise, mustard and seasoning are sometimes referred to collectively as [condiments](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/condiment?q=condiments)
6. Oil and vinegar is called the [dressing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dressing)
7. Guacamole (made from avocados) is a typical [dip](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dip#dip)
8. Turmeric, paprika, chilli powder, black pepper etc. are [spices](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spice).

None of the above can be described as a side-dish. They are ingredients which *enhance* the flavour of dishes.

Comment: Typically though you don't serve the ingredients of the dish along with the dish as you might a chutney. There are many different flavor enhancers, but my understanding is that the question is looking for the name of the 'accoutrements' (not the right word for food, I know) for non-Indian dishes that parallel the chutneys and other wonderful little bowls of intense flavor that accompany Indian dishes. I think your list is helpful, but maybe you could highlight the entry that most closely matches what Maulik was specifically asking about.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks, but the answer supplied by David Richerby is the one that addresses specifically  Maulik's question, my contribution was meant only to supplement his and boatseller's answers.

Answer (score 2):

Crudely : "fixins".  As in "..with all the fixins."

Condiments, we call them condiments. Oregano is a generally a garnish. 
This is even if they are spread, or poured, or dipped into.
They will be savoury. They will be fluid, and sometimes chunky.

(Chutneys, salsa, and grain mustard can be quite chunky).

We might include (or not) :

- Sweet preparations such as Honey or Golden Syrup
- Gravy (for hot chips or fries), gravy is generally served on the plate ?
- Jus, reductions, oyster sauce, soy sauce.

Mayonaise, Tartare Sauce, Thousand Island, and Balsamic are sometimes "dressings".

Comment: I think I'd class soy sauce as a condiment. Also, given that gravy, jus, reductions, oyster sauce and soy sauce *are* savoury, I'm not sure why you're including them in your list of things that aren't condiments because they aren't savoury.

Comment: Umami ? Canadians use gravy as a sauce ? Belgians use mayonaise as a sauce ? Australians use vinegar. Usage varies. When does something become a topping ? I suppose if they are served separately ala "cruet set" (I like this answer) they qualify as sauces. Adding pepper to gravy makes it a sauce. What about melted butter, with or without garlic ?. Horseradish, wasabi, hot mustard are applied after the meal is served and cannot be poured. Oregano, rosemary, parsley may come applied (hence a garnish).

Answer (score 1):

"Condiments" is the closest word but you could also use "cruet", especially if there is a charge. "Cruet extra" was a running joke about boarding houses in the UK but apparently it did happen: ['And the cruet came extra...'](http://www.yorkshireeveningpost.co.uk/news/news-features/and-the-cruet-came-extra-1-2267780) (Yorkshire Post).

Comment: The cruet is the container in which the substances are served (source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cruet)). I'm not aware of it being used for the substances themselves and, to my ear, the word sounds very old-fashioned.

Comment: The cruet is the container but was also used to refer to the contents as well. "Pass the cruet" would mean pass the mustard, salt and pepper, vinegar et cetera. "Cruet extra" would mean being charged for the use of condiments. It is old fashioned though, I admit!

Comment: "Pass the cruet" (or even more properly, "the cruet set", since "the cruet" is a single container) would mean "pass the containers that hold the mustard, salt and pepper, vinegar, etc., and, by the way, I'd prefer it if you didn't empty them first." In the same way, you might say "pass the bottle" to mean "give me the wine" but you'd never refer to wine as "bottle".

Comment: @DavidRicherby judging linguistic discussions by analogy is fruitless. You may never have seen the accompaniments to a meal described as "the cruet" but there is a link to an example in this answer. Also in common english usage one may not refer to wine by its container, but that has no bearing whatever on whether in common english usage one refers to some other thing by its container. Do you have a lot of evidence for the phrase "Pass the cruet set" ?

Comment: @Dominic The linked article contains the phrase "Use of the cruet". That seems strongly to be talking about an object, since one doesn't tend to "use" foods.

Comment: @DavidRicherby really? don't you use salt in your cooking? In any case it's also valid as a synecdoche.

Comment: @Dominic I might "use" salt in the kitchen while cooking but I don't think I'd "use" it at the table. But, putting that aside, do you have any evidence that "cruet" is used to refer to the contents rather than just the container? The dictionaries I looked in (Oxford Dictionaries, and just now the full OED and Merriam-Webster) all only talk about the container. Why are you claiming that "cruet" a valid synecdoche for things that are put in a cruet, when "bottle" is clearly not a valid synecdoche for wine?

Comment: @Dominic Actually, I can't think of any foodstuff that is referred to by the name of its container, though I'm sure that, if I look away for fifteen minutes, there'll be a million examples addressed to me below.

Comment: @DavidRicherby usage is validity. if we use it as such, then we use it as such. if we don't then we don't. When I say "pass the cruet" (which I don't but my grandmother did) she was very much interested in the whole package. Just as when I say "pass the salt" I really do mean the salt and the salt cellar together. Language is not logical. That we do use a synecdoche in one instance but not in another is just how we roll.

Comment: @Dominic You still haven't provided any evidence at all that salt is being referred to as "cruet" in the phrase "pass the cruet". I have provided evidence to the contrary (dictionary definitions including the OED, which is strongly descriptivist, and the analogy with wine bottles).

Comment: What @David said (repeatedly). I'm old enough that I can (just about) still use **cruet** fairly "naturally". But I have *never* heard anyone use it to specifically identify the *contents* of the *cruet [**set**]*.